# How to press Mark As Read Button in Notification with the Help of NotificationListnerService?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

```
public class NotificationListenerExampleService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
 //I am sucessfully Receiving Notification 
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){

   }
}
```

I am able to read Notification content with onNotificationPosted(). How can I press Mark As Read Button in Notification?

Answer (score 0):

> after spending some time i am able to do that with the help of below
>   code.

```
public class NotificationListenerExampleService extends 
NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
//I am sucessfully Receiving Notification 
try {

    if (sbn.getNotification().actions != null) {
        for (Notification.Action action: sbn.getNotification().actions) {

            if (action.title.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Mark as read")) {

                PendingIntent intent = action.actionIntent;

                 try {
                     intent.send();
                 } catch(PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){  
 }
}
```